# Possible to align sequence of align operators?

Tags: php, coding-style, php-cs-fixer

Is there a rule in [PHP-CS-FIXER](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) 2.15.3 to align a sequence of equal symbols?

For example to change

```
    $a = 3;
    $codeWord = 4;
    $foo = 'xyz';
```

into

```
    $a        = 3;
    $codeWord = 4;
    $foo      = 'xyz';
```

?

I have read almost every description of every rule at https://mlocati.github.io/php-cs-fixer-configurator/#version:2.15|configurator but I didn't find any. Did I missed it, or is there actuality no such rule?

Comment: I deleted my comment, saw you were asking about FIXER. I know of no such rule.

Comment: can u please share the purpose? maybe you got alternate suggestions.

Comment: @devpro my purpose is pretty primitive. I simply find it looks cleaner when the equal signs are aligned like in the second example.

Comment: is Tab key not working???

Comment: @devpro ofcourse tab key is working. ;) But I would like that they get automatically aligned when I don't do it myself. Thats why I use php-cs-fixer. Before I write my custom script I wanted to find out if this already exists.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using `binary_operator_spaces` fixer.

Add it only for `=` operator with

```php
    'binary_operator_spaces' => ['operators' => ['=' => 'align_single_space']],
```

or for every binary operator:

```php
    'binary_operator_spaces' => ['default' => 'align_single_space'],
```